# How to change access rights to a spreadsheet from Editor to Viewer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the script in the spreadsheet that the editor run:

```
function ed2view() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var eds = ss.getEditors();
  var ed = eds[1];
  ss.removeEditor(ed);
  ss.addViewer(ed);
}
```

It does not work, because, apparently, by the time addViewer() the rights have already been revoked.

If just addViewer(), without the previous removeEditor(), also does not work: [If the user was already on the list of editors, this method has no effect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addvieweremailaddress).

On the other hand, through the interface of the spreadsheet, the editor can lower its access rights to the Viewer.

Please advise how to correctly change access rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task has a solution if you do not manipulate access through the Spreadsheet file, but use the Advanced Drive Service.

```
function run() {
  driveChangeMeRole_(FILE_ID, EMAIL);
}

/**
 * Downgrade you in the rights from the editor to the viewer
 * @param {string} fileId The file id
 * @param {string} email You can pass your email and downgrade youself
 * @returns {void}
 */
function driveChangeMeRole_(fileId, email) {
  var permissionId = Drive.Permissions.getIdForEmail(email);
  var resource = Drive.newPermission();
  resource.role = 'reader';
  /* You can stay as a commenter
  resource.additionalRoles = ['commenter']; */
  Drive.Permissions.update(resource, fileId, permissionId.id);
}
```

You need to enable the Drive API: Script Editor: Resources/Advanced Features and in [Google API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
The task was decided by @oshilaer [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881948/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%81-editor-%D0%B4%D0%BE-viewer)

Comment: are you sure the editor can use that code, didn't worked for me.

Comment: @JSmith The code works, I checked.
What error do you get?

Comment: it works if you are the owner but as an editor I get `Project 46022463242 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Drive API by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=46022463242 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. (line 32, file "ed2view")`

Comment: There is not an `ed2view` or a `line 32` in the code. The full example is [there](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/drive_change_user_role/drive_change_user_role.js)

Comment: @oshliaer I've tried directly on the script linked to the spreadsheet that why I get this code. I'll try on an unlinked script.

Comment: @BorisBaublys right that works good job. but it doesn't work from the script linked to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

try this if you want an editor to change other editor's status:

```
function ed2view() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editorArray = ss.getEditors();
  var userMail = editorArray[1].getEmail();
  ss.removeEditor(editorArray[1]);
  ss.addViewer(userMail);
}
```

In your code your trying to pass as argument a [`User`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user) object instead of an email adress of type `string` in `addViewer()`

if you are an editor and not the owner and you want to change your permission status with App Script well you just can't,still the editor can go into the share settings of the spreadsheet and change his permission status to 'read-only' then confirm.

Unfortunately you can't do that programmatically.

Comment: Thank you, @JSmith, you are right about String! However, the script does not work anyway. The editor loses all rights.
Maybe after removeEditor() at once ActiveSpreadsheet is deleted and accordingly there is no ss? Maybe I need to first save the spreadsheet ID to a variable and then go to addViewer() by id?

Comment: @BorisBaublys can you share the spreasheet please?

Comment: Oh sure. Please write your email - I will give you the right to edit.

Comment: @BorisBaublys just share the link please I'll send you a request

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A4SyOjLGfW93OKNGmyo-kG703Lr_V5xP9ZzjQF2edIY/edit)

Comment: It's hard for me to agree that the editor can not change his access rights programmatically ...
Because I need to do this.
And because I was told that this code can solve the problem: [link](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet.users/spreadsheet.users.js)
But it does not work either.

Comment: @BorisBaublys as told in the post, the code you gave me works if you are another editor or the owner of the sheet. But an editor cannot programmatically loose all his right and continue executing your function to change his status this is out of logic, this would be a security issue.

Comment: It seems that you are right, and I marked the answer.
But, perhaps, let the editor lose its right, and let the script run not on behalf of the editor, but on behalf of the owner. What if I use onEdit()?

Comment: @BorisBaublys if you use `onEdit()` it will be the same problem because on edit cannot trigger if the editor loose his right to edit. Plus I don't see how you can give the ex-editor the owner title seems really strange.

Comment: There will not be a remove, only a change if you do not manipulate users and access through the Spreadsheet. If you use Advanced Drive Service?
Look at the solution from **oshliaer** [here.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881948/Как-изменить-права-доступа-к-таблице-с-editor-до-viewer/883700#883700)
If it works, then it turns out I hurried with the marking of the answer.

Comment: @BorisBaublys well try it. I can't read russian but from what I understand I highly doubt an editor can have access to the drive of the owner, perhaps if you get the shared file from your drive you can but that I don't know. Please try the solution and if it works answer your own question and mark it as answer. I really would like to know if it works

Comment: @BorisBaublys please Activate DRIVE API in your Google API console for your spreadsheet and come back to me.